# python IDLE find line breaks

Tags: python, regex, python-idle

I just installed and ran the [pep8 Python style guide checker](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pep8). I get a few errors and warnings. One of them is W291 trailing whitespace. My question is, how do I in IDLE search for line breaks (or tab indentations for that matter). I tried ctrl+f using the Regular expression option and searching for \n, but that doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Kindly delete this question, if it doesn't belong on stackoverflow, as it is not a programming question as such. Thanks.

Comment: What regex have you tried?

Comment: I would think that a regex like `\s+$` would do the trick.

Comment: It is related to a tool used for programming - so your question is fine :) I do however recommend that you migrate to a fully fledged IDE...

Comment: You replied to my post before it was deleted, so I undeleted it. A blank space followed by a dollar sign of course works. Doh! Sorry for posting. @mgilson can you leave answer? Otherwise I will delete my question.

Comment: @Lix - Wouldn't this be better on SuperUser though since it deals primarily with an application and not code?

Comment: @iCodez -- it deals with regex which is a pretty common SO category.  Really, the regex provided is more or less tool agnostic.  I think it's probably OK here, but there certainly could be a case made for migrating it.

Comment: @iCodez - just because a question is "better" for a certain site it doesn't mean it is off-topic for another. You might be correct - but it's still valid for [so] as stated in the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) (3rd bullet).

Comment: For example one can use `^ +and` to correct W503 and ` +$` to correct W293.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After giving it a try, the regex `\s+$` does work.

explanation:  `\s` matches any single whitespace character.  `+` makes it match a series of whitespace characters.  `$` matches the end of the line.  So, we're matching a series of whitespace characters immediately before the end of the line.